# Finishing stream with iterator vs collect?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Say, I want to filter a list and return the filtered list, but iterator would suffice too. Which of the following options is preferable and why? `Stream.iterator()` or `Stream.collect(ListCollector)`.

Comment: These options are different, you can consume an iterator only once, a list as often as you like. Depends what you want, if the iterator suffices, why use something else then?

Comment: They are different. Iterator returns an Iterator over List, but Collect will returns a List.

Comment: There's also e.g. a third option `forEach(Consumer)`. It depends on what you're doing with the result.

Comment: If ``.iterator()`` is an option, why not just keep it as a ``Stream`` as it offers many more capabilities?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut well, I need the result only once. But, well list looks more aesthetically to me. I'm just trying to understand, whether returning an iterator is internally the same as collecting stream first and then returning result's iterator. Or is it something entirely different? For me returning a list is more clear, because, as you said, there are no limitations on usage.

Comment: If your usage is limited on only iterating through your results, then the limitation on usage has its right to exist. Use forEach() if you want all the advantages of java streams API, collect() if you need the collection API.

Comment: The `iterator()` method was designed as an escape hatch for cases that could not be expressed with the existing stream methods.  So in all cases, if there's an alternative to `iterator()`, you should prefer the alternative.

Answer (score 20):

There is a fundamental difference between `Stream.iterator()` and `.collect(Collectors.toList()) .iterator()`. The latter will process all items of the stream in order to store them into a collection. In contrast, `Stream.iterator()` will just return a wrapper around the `Stream`’s `Spliterator` which will process all items lazily like all other stream operations do.

E.g. when you write

```
Iterator<String> it=IntStream.range(0, 100).mapToObj(i->{
    System.out.println("processing "+i);
    return String.valueOf(i);
}).iterator();

if(it.hasNext()) System.out.println("first: "+it.next());
if(it.hasNext()) System.out.println("second: "+it.next());
return;// I don’t care about the remaining values
```

it will print:

```
processing 0
first: 0
processing 1
second: 1
```

while

```
Iterator<String> it=IntStream.range(0, 100).mapToObj(i->{
    System.out.println("processing "+i);
    return String.valueOf(i);
}).collect(Collectors.toList()).iterator();

if(it.hasNext()) System.out.println("first: "+it.next());
if(it.hasNext()) System.out.println("second: "+it.next());
return;// I don’t care about the remaining values
```

will print

```
processing 0
processing 1
processing 2
processing 3
processing 4
processing 5
processing 6
processing 7
processing 8
processing 9
processing 10
…
processing 90
processing 91
processing 92
processing 93
processing 94
processing 95
processing 96
processing 97
processing 98
processing 99
first: 0
second: 1
```

That said, if all you need is an `Iterator` you should *not* enforce collecting the values before requesting it, unless you have a strong reason to do so (e.g., if the source is a file, you might want to finish the operation before returning the iterator).

Comment: So, basically you're saying that, in case of returning stream's iterator, actual stream processing (all the operations that are to be made on a stream), will be made upon each call of `iterator.next`.

Comment: Right, there are only a few exceptions, e.g. if you use `sorted`, it might require to (pre)process all items before being able to pass the first element. But usually, that’s right, the stream progresses as required by your calls to either `hasNext` or `next`.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't offer it as one of your alternatives, but I'd suggest that you consider returning a Stream to the caller. If you're willing to return an Iterator to the caller, a Stream is probably much more convenient. ([Jean Logeart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510619/finishing-stream-with-iterator-vs-collect#comment49096907_30510619) also suggested this in a comment.)

It sounds like you have an internal collection of items (or whatever) and you're using streams to filter them by some criteria that you don't want to expose to your caller. Given a filtered stream, there are several alteratives for what to return:

1. a List: `stream.collect(toList())`
2. an Iterator from the stream: `stream.iterator()`
3. an Iterator from a collected list: `stream.collect(toList()).iterator()`
4. the Stream itself: `stream`

Which is best depends a bit on what the caller wants to do with the return value. If you **know** the caller will always want to store all the filtered items, you might as well do the caller a favor by collecting such a list yourself.

However, the caller might want to do something different. Suppose the caller wants to look for a particular item, or count the number of filtered items, or see if there any filtered items at all. In those cases, collecting the items into a list is mostly a waste.

Returning an Iterator from the filtered stream buys you laziness in that the collection isn't created up-front. However, dealing with an Iterator is potentially cumbersome for the caller.

If the caller wants a collection, something like this would be necesary:

```
Iterator<Item> iter = getFilteredItems();
List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>();
iter.forEachRemaining(result::add);
```

If the caller wants to look for a particular item, it's worse:

```
Item foundItem = null;
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Item current = iter.next();
    if (targetId.equals(current.getId())) {
        foundItem = current;
        break;
    }
}
if (foundItem != null) {
    // found it!
} else {
    // not found
}
```

Counting the number of filtered items can be done either incrementing a counter in a `while (iter.hasNext())` loop or by incrementing an `AtomicInteger` within `forEachRemaining`. Testing whether there are any filtered items at all is fortunately quite simple, just a call to `iter.hasNext()`.

Returning an Iterator over a collected List is the worst of both worlds. You pay the up-front cost of collecting the List even if the caller doesn't need it, and the caller might have to do extra work to run through all the elements as shown above. [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30511761/1441122) has explained the differences well.

Finally, returning a Stream offers the efficiency of laziness and is probably the most flexible all around. If you're filtering using streams already, just return the stream:

```
Stream<Item> getFilteredItems() {
    return myInternalCollection.stream()
                               .filter(...);
}
```

If the caller wants a list of the items, it's pretty simple:

```
List<Item> = getFilteredItems().collect(toList());
```

If the caller wants to find a particular item, it's also pretty simple:

```
Optional<Item> item = getFilteredItems()
                        .filter(it -> targetId.equals(it.getId()))
                        .findAny();
if (item.isPresent()) {
    // found it!
} else {
    // not found
}
```

(The `Optional` class itself has a rich set of APIs that might allow you to avoid the `ifPresent()` test.)

Counting the items is just:

```
long count = getFilteredItems().count();
```

and testing whether there are any filtered items at all is:

```
boolean any = getFilteredItems().findAny().isPresent();
```

Returning a stream keeps things lazy for as long as possible, and affords the most flexibility to the caller.

Comment: I also think it's the best solution and already converted dozens of methods returning `List` or array to returning streams (removing the verb from the method name like `filteredItems()` instead of `getFilteredItems()` like it's done in JDK). Nice to hear that my approach is correct.